# How to call component reference from another component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use [react-notification-system](https://github.com/igorprado/react-notification-system) library, and found my code more or less like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import Notification from 'react-notification-system';

class Notif extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.notificationSystem = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // how to export this?
    this.notificationSystem = this.refs.notificationSystem;
  }

  render() {
    return <Notification ref="notificationSystem" />;
  }

}

export default Notif;
```

How can I export that `notificationSystem` so I can use it everywhere?

Comment: Why do you want only the reference, but not `Notif` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Use global widget.

Just add a global widget as follow.

```
var _component

export function set(component) {
    _component = component
}

export function get() {
    return _component
}
```

And then in your `AppComponent` register it:

```
import {set} from './notify'
class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        set(this.refs.notificationSystem)
    }
}
```

In any other component, call it:

```
import {get} from './notify'
class AnyComponent extends React.Component {
    alert() {
        get().doSomething()
    }
}
```

2. Use react context to store it as a global props for all component.

Comment: Can you explain more on context with an example? So I can mark your answer as `done`, please.

Comment: The code is toooooo long so I cannot post it without test. You can do it with the official document: [Context - React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html)

Comment: Yeah actually I already read about context, BUT I need to update it right? At the moment when `componentDidMount` triggered, I need suggestion how to handle that.

Comment: Two ways: first is return a referenced object in `getChildContext()`, second is trigger a update event when your app mounted to flush context.
Maybe this is help: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#updating-context

Comment: Ok, I have done it using context, thank you for the help.